# Bluetooth headphone does not work in Fallout 4?

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-4, hardware

I have a **bluetooth headphone** - "JBL Wireless On-Ear Headphones T450BT" it works when I play music or watch movies. 
But if I start **Fallout 4** , the Audio starts playing from the Laptop speaker and there is no sound in the Headphones.
( I have a Lenovo Laptop G50 - 80 ). If I use my wired Headphones it works.

### How to fix this? Couldn't find anything online.

Edit: This issue automatically got fixed after some windows update (*sigh).

Answer (score 1):

Your music player and movie player have their own control over which device to use for audio playback.

I will assume Windows 10.

On the lower right hand corner, click on your volume control:

[image]

Above the slider, you can see your currently active sound device.

If it isn't set to your USB headphones, change it.  This should solve the problem.